# How does a Yoledet remove her impurity for korbanot?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, pregnancy-birth

Does the tuma of a Yoledet expire?

What I mean is that she goes to the mikve on the 8th or 15th night and is permitted to her husband ( even if she's still bleeding ), but is still impure for purposes of the Beit Mikdash and sacrafices until the 40th or 80th night when she brings a korban.

Does she go to the mikveh a second time, or does the tuma just expire, or is it the act of bringing the korban which removes the tuma?

Obviously I'm dealing here with the biblical issues, and not how we practice today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mishna ([Chaggiga](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h2c.htm) 3:3) says:

> אונן ומחוסר כיפורים צריכין טבילה לקודש, אבל לא לתרומה

A Mechusar Kapparah - someone who is finished with the other purifications, but lacking bringing the Karbanos, has to go to the Mikvah [after bringing the Korbanos, as we shall see] before being able to eat Kodshim (Korbanos meat, like the Karban pesach), but not Teruma.

The Rambam ([Metamei Mischav UMoshav 5:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a405.htm)) says:

> נמצאת למד שהיולדת, בתוך ימי טוהר--אוכלת במעשר ופוסלת את התרומה, כטבול יום כמו שיתבאר.  ואם נפל מרוקה ומדם טהרתה על כיכר של תרומה, הרי הוא בטהרתו--שמשקה טבול יום טהור כמו שיתבאר; ומטמאה את הקודשים כוולד הטומאות, עד שתשלים ימי טוהר ותהיה טהורה לכול.  וייראה לי שמאחר שהיא מטמאה את הקודש, שהיא צריכה טבילה בסוף, ואחר כך תיגע בקודש, אף על פי שאינה צריכה טבילה אחרת לאכילת התרומה

That a Yoledes before the 33/66 days are up can eat Maaser, but not Teruma, like a Tevul Yom, and she makes Kodshim Tamei. The literal reading of the Rambam would say that after the days are finished (and nothing else) she is Tahor, but has to go to the Mikvah to eat Kodshim, and that this Mikvah is his own idea, not previously mentioned in the Talmud, etc. No mention of the Korbanos requirement.

The Ra'avad argues, citing the Mishna, and wonders what on earth the Rambam is talking about. The Kesef Mishna points to where the Rambam in Avos HaTumos Chapter 12 says that until someone lacking a Korban brings it, they are not allowed to touch Kodshim, and interprets the Rambam as meaning that when the time passes and she is Tahor from everything *by bringing the Korbanos* she still has to go to the Mikvah in order to touch Kodshim.

So to sum up, she can eat Maaser after 7/14 days and Mikvah, and eat Teruma after Korbanos, and eat Kodshim after a second time in the Mikva after that.

Comment: Do you know if anyone interprets the Rambam the other way, as not requiring Korbanot (bedieved or something)?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of such an opinion.